# Program Crashes when making call to connect()

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

I threw in some print statements and found my program crashes when it makes a call to `connect()`.  I did a few google searches and looked through the code and am unsure of what is happening, I called `GetLastError()` before the connect call and nothing is going wrong, nothing is going wrong in the program and then the whole thing crashes immediately.
its pretty obviously not even trying to connect to a server and nothing will be printed out after because it has crashed.
So, I dont know what is going on here and none of my usual methods will work because the program is crashing without putting out any output, and nothing running up to it is going wrong.

```
WSAData wsaData;

int iResult;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {

#ifdef debug    
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
#endif

    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
    *ptr = NULL,
    hints;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

#define DEFAULT_PORT "80"

std::string www = "tildetictac.x10host.com";
// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(www.c_str(), DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
#ifdef debug
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n%d\n", iResult, GetLastError());
#endif
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
else {
#ifdef debug
    std::cout << "success \n";
#endif
}

SOCKET connectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

printf("error: %d", GetLastError());

// Connect to server.
iResult = connect(connectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
std::cout << "2"; 
// this doesn't get printed before the crash, so its for sure connect()
```

Comment: The only way the code could crash at the `connect` call would be if `ptr` is not valid. And I don't see it being assigned a non-null value anywhere.

Comment: Additionally, `connectSocket` is set to `INVALID_SOCKET` and then you try to connect it. Seems like you have only written half your program.

Comment: What are the exact values of the parameters passed to the function call?

Comment: connectSocket is going to be invalid and ptr is going to be null.  That is probably the problem

Comment: As stated above, connectSocket is not a valid socket, you need to call socket() first to get a valid socket descriptor from the OS.

Comment: `cout` is buffered, so you don't really know if you reached `"2"` or not. You need to flush the output buffer while trace-debugging (`std::endl` is convenient), or use `std::cerr`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign `result` to `ptr`. Otherwise you are dereferencing NULL pointer, which will lead to crash.

```
    std::string www = "tildetictac.x10host.com";
    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(www.c_str(), DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
    #ifdef debug
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n%d\n", iResult, GetLastError());
    #endif
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else {
    #ifdef debug
        std::cout << "success \n";
    #endif
    }

    ptr = result; //ADDED

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    connectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (connectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
```

Please have a look at this example:

[Complete Winsock Client Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591.aspx)